# Split data frame column when square brackets

Tags: r, dataframe, split, separator, tidyr

I have a data frame with some model estimations. Depending on the observation the estimation has just a value or a value together with a confidence interval between square brackets. By the way, the variable is a character (I guess that I need to change it some-when)

```
df<-data.frame(c("5","3","8 [3 - 5]")
```

I would like to split this data frame column (x) into two columns. A first one for the estimated values (y) and a second one for the confidence interval with or without brackets (z).

I have tried with tidyr::separate and tidyr::split (I am big fun of the dplyr family:-), but I do not get the wished result.

```
tidyr::separate(col=x,into=c("y","z"),sep="//[")
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `extract`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, x, into = c("y", "z"), "(\\d+)\\s*(.*)")
```

---

Or use the `extra` argument in `separate`

```
separate(df, x, into = c("y", "z"), "\\s+", extra = "merge")
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(x= c("5","3","8 [3 - 5]"))
```

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly the type of solution I was looking for. Two questions: 1) What do the "magic" code in sep= means:-)? 2) I get an error when applying your code: "joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector. Error in names(l) <- enc2utf8(into) : 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]" Do you know why?

Comment: I solved the issue with a slightly different code. I removed the white spaces first and I applied tidyr::separate then without sep=. Honestly, I do not know why it did not work before and why it works now, but it is ok so. `df$var<-gsub(" ","",df$var)` `separate(col=var,into=c("var1","var2"),extra="merge")`

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
library("stringr")
df <- data.frame(c("5", "3", "8 [3 - 5]")) 
df2 = str_split_fixed(string = df[,1], pattern = "\\[", n = 2)               
df2[,2] = gsub(pattern = "\\]", replacement = "", x = df2[,2])
```